# Why Spring Boot Application is not working after Deployment on Azure Web app

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

Could please anyone help me with 404 Error when I try to access the api Url deployed on azure.Due to admin rights , not able to install azure CLI as if now.So I have followed below steps.

Step 1:
Created Spring boot application that is returning string "Hello" from HelloController and tested the code on local and it was up and running.

Step 2:
Create web app on azure portal and configured local git repository.

Step 3:
On my local,I copied the local git url and made git cloning.

Step 4:
Inside Webapps folder created ,I have placed the war file by renaming it to the ROOT.war

Step 4:
Ran the below command:

git status

git add .

git commit -m"Test"

git push origin master

Step 4:
Went on the azure portal and checked the ROOT folder and War File,it was succesfully deployed.
[Click here For the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kjUh.png)

Step 6:
When I hit on the url,I am getting 404 error:
[Click here for Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gf1m.png)

Code Snippet For Controller:

```
 package io.javabrains.springbootstarter;


 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

 @RestController
 public class HelloController {
      @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World RESTful with Spring Boot";
     }  
   }
```

Code Snippet For Spring Boot Starter:

```
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class,args);

   }

 }
```

Pom.xml:

In Pom.xml, Configuration was created in the very last by running maven plugin(goal:mvn-webapp:config) in spring boot that created the default configuration.I then mapped the same values in configuration tag that I have created in my azure portal.Goal was to just check what configutation properties are created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">  
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
 <groupId>io.javabrains.springbootquickstart</groupId>  
 <artifactId>course-api-test</artifactId>  
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
 <packaging>war</packaging>  
 <name>Java Brains Course Api</name>  
 <parent> 
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
 <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>  
 <relativePath/>  
 <!-- lookup parent from repository --> 
 </parent>  
 <dependencies> 
 <!-- WEB -->  
 <dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
 </dependency>  
 <!-- <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>--> 
 </dependencies>  
 <properties> 
 <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
 </properties>  
 <build> 
   <plugins> 
    <plugin> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
  </plugin>  
  <plugin> 
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>  
    <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>1.7.0</version>  
    <configuration>
      <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
      <resourceGroup>first-azure-application-28minutes</resourceGroup>
      <appName>CourseapiTest</appName>
      <pricingTier>F1</pricingTier>
      <region>South Central US</region>
      <appSettings>
      <property>
      <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
      <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
      </property>
      </appSettings>
      <runtime>
        <os>windows</os>
        <javaVersion>jre8</javaVersion>
        <webContainer>TOMCAT 9</webContainer>
      </runtime>
      <deployment>
              <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                           <includes>
                              <include>*.war</include>
                           </includes>
                    </resource>
              </resources>
      </deployment>
    </configuration>
  </plugin> 
    </plugins> 
    </build> 
   </project>
```

application.properties:

server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK

Errors: Under Diagonose and Section In Azure:

[Click here for Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Bro.png)

[Click here for Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f690e.png)

Answer (score 2):

To deploy a spring boot app to Azure App Service, it is recommended to deploy jar file.

I followed [this tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin) and it works fine. If you always see the default page, you need to add a web.config file.

[image]

The files under wwwroot directory.

[image]

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\app.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the missing peace. The web.config was never generated & uploaded in my case from vscode. Had to create & upload it manually using FTP.